# Understand a join query

Tags: mysql, join

I want to understand the course of a join query.

```
SELECT template.*
FROM template_item AS template
JOIN items ON items.id = template.id
WHERE items.user_id = 1 AND template.type != 'short';

SELECT template.*
FROM template_item AS template
JOIN items ON items.id = template.id AND items.user_id = 1
WHERE template.type != 'short';
```

Which one is better ?

In the first query, as the "join" goes , it takes all items and apply filter after  "where". Right ?

*Sorry for my bad english , i'm french.*

Comment: Check execution plan

Comment: Why not get the explain plan? I would think these may be the same

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: what we are saying is plop the word `explain` in front of each and run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT template.*
FROM template_item AS template
JOIN items ON items.id = template.id AND items.user_id = 1
WHERE template.type != 'short';
```

Might be the better one,since it negates the column during 'Joining' itself.

Try

```
EXPLAIN SELECT template.*
    FROM template_item AS template
    JOIN items ON items.id = template.id AND items.user_id = 1
    WHERE template.type != 'short';
```

AND

```
EXPLAIN SELECT template.*
FROM template_item AS template
JOIN items ON items.id = template.id
WHERE items.user_id = 1 AND template.type != 'short';
```

See the difference in 'no.of rows'.First query will be efficient when it comes across large data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, any difference ?

Comment: What was the out put of "EXPLAIN"?If you find it useful, please mark it as answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, and thank you for correcting my post.